# Multipage Application Form with Sessions or Database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

I want to build a 5-page application form with php, where a user has to enter about 50 data entries (name, age, other details ...) which should be saved in the main database if the form is completed.

I wonder, which of the following approaches performs better:

**A)** After completing a page, save all entries in a big $_SESSION array. At the end save all entries from the $_SESSION array in the main database

or

**B)**  After completing a page, save all entries in a small database. Save in the $_SESSION array only the id of the small database and the page where the user currently is on the form. At the end save all entries from the $_small database to the main database.

I am not sure if it leads to problems when storing about 50 entries in the $_SESSION array, especially if many users use the form. Therefore I was thinking that **B** might be better. But if not, I would not want to make the extra effort of maintaining an extra local database if there is no difference in the performance of the website. Are there maybe other downsides one should be aware of when using *A)* or *B)* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there are no big and small databases, there are only big and small database **tables**. There is no need to have separate schemas for each page so in the second approach you should have multiple tables and not multiple databases.

Regardless, the first approach is actually better because if the user cancels or never follows along on all the five pages you will be left with useless information in your tables. Storing the entries in `$_SESSION` is also faster since you don't have to query the database after every form submit, just the final one. The only downside of the second approach is that if a user leaves your page and then later returns they will need to input everything from scratch whereas in the first approach they can continue from where they left off (that's provided you have a way to tell the users apart with something like a unique id or email). Still first approach is the best.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I ment tables ofc. But your last sentecen should be **still the first approach**... right?

Comment: @Adam yes sure, my bad I fixed, I mean first approach. Sessions are the way to go